# Google Chart long Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

.Hi I've been trying to add [google calendar chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/calendar) to my project but there is something wrong that I don't understand.

My chart is on a pop-up panel which **triggered by button click** And here is my code;

The button click function:

```
function Detail(id)
{
   google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["calendar"] });
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  //callback for chart
   $.ajax({
        //Some stuff here
   });

   $.ajax({
       //Some other stuff here
   });
}
```

So, as you can see after button click drawChart must be run.

```
function drawChart(){
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'done/miss' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: { html: true } });

  dataTable.addRows([
                    [new Date(2017, 3, 9), 10, '<div style="width:40px; height:40px;">TESTtest</div>']
        ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'));

   var options = {
            title: "test",
            height: '100%',
        };
   chart.draw(dataTable, options);
   $('#PopUpDiv').show();
}
```

When I click the button page locks for few sec and Firefox says: "**A script stopped working or no response anymore Script: https://www.gstatic.com/charts…sapi_compiled_format_module.js:179**"

The code looks really simple and correct. I don't understand what is happening, so some help would be great. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :** I've created code snipped and try this code on there and it works. Now i'm confuced :(

```js
function Detail()
{
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["calendar"] });
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
}

function drawChart(){
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Date' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'number', id: 'done/miss' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: { html: true } });

  dataTable.addRows([
                    [new Date(2017, 3, 9), 10, '<div style="width:40px; height:40px;">TESTtest</div>']
        ]);
  var chart = new google.visualization.Calendar(document.getElementById('calendar'));

   var options = {
            title: "test",
            height: '100%',
        };
   chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="Detail()">click it</button>
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I closed the VS and restarted the project and somehow problem solved. So the code is fine. Thanks everyone for attention.